# Por qué mi else no funciona?

Tags: c++, c

Estoy ayudando a mi novio con un trabajo práctico y no podemos darnos cuenta de por qué cuando buscamos el importe para que nos muestre el primer empleado que pusimos nos dice que no existe o no nos lo muestra y no entendemos el por qué. Alguien tiene alguna idea?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish");

int cant;

cant=0;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,13});printf("¿Cuántas facturas va a ingresar? ");fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&cant);

char nombres[30][cant];

float importes[cant];

int cont1=0;
int cont2=0;
int promedio=0;
char continuar='S';

system("cls");

for(int x=0;x<cant;x++)
{
    while(continuar == 'S' || continuar == 's')
    {
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){10,10+1});printf("Ingrese el nombre del cliente: ");fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&nombres);

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){10,12+1});printf("Ingrese el importe del cliente: ");fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%f",&importes);

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,17+1});printf("%s  $  %f", nombres[x], importes[x]);fflush(stdin);

        cont1++;

        if(importes[x] > 1000)
        {
            cont2++;
        }

        promedio += importes[x];

        SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,19});printf("\n\n¿Desea continuar? S para si, N para no\n\n");fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s",&continuar);
        system("cls");
    }
    }
    printf("\nSe cargaron: %d facturas", cont1);
    printf("\nSe cargaron: %d facturas que superan $1000", cont2);
    printf("\nEl promedio de todas las facturas es de: %d",promedio/cont1);


float impbusc=0;
continuar='S';

do
{
    printf("\n\nIngrese el importe para buscar una factura: ");
    scanf("%f", &impbusc);

    for(int x=0;x<cont1;x++)
    {
        if(importes[x] == impbusc)
        {
            printf("\nEl importe a buscar es %f y pertenece a %s", impbusc, nombres[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEl importe que ingreso no existe!!!\n");
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nDesea continuar? S para si, N para no\n\n");
    scanf("%s",&continuar);

}while(continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');


}
```

Creemos que el problema esta **acá** y que el else no funciona, ya que no se nos ocurre ninguna otra opción pero tampoco sabemos como corregirlo:

```
do
{
    printf("\n\nIngrese el importe para buscar una factura: ");
    scanf("%f", &impbusc);

    for(int x=0;x<cont1;x++)
    {
        if(importes[x] == impbusc)
        {
            printf("\nEl importe a buscar es %f y pertenece a %s", impbusc, nombres[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nEl importe que ingreso no existe!!!\n");
        }
    }
```

Todo funciona menos esa parte que queremos obtener el primer nombre buscando el importe. Desde ya muchas gracias!! (:

Comment: Eso no es c#, es c o c++, verifica bien el lenguaje

Comment: @Japv cuando lo publique en el foro en ingles me dijeron que era c# y había puesto c y c++ :/, ahí lo cambie igualmente

Comment: Lo que yo haría sería un menú.
Aparte otra cosa. Pide la cantidad de facturas y después pregunta si desea continuar. Como que la pregunta no tiene sentido.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro yes, pensamos lo mismo y lo consultamos pero nos dijeron q lo dejemos así

Comment: No se por qué importes tiene que ser un arreglo de float y no una variable común o simple

Comment: @AlejandroCaro porque puede ser q el importe tenga un numero decimal

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver. Si tiene decimales puede ser una variable tipo float, pero no necesariamente un arreglo. Si pones float importes[cant]; lo que estás haciendo es crear un arreglo variable en cant que se llama importes. En cambio si haces float importes estás creando una variable tipo float. Son cosas distintas.

Comment: ¿Dónde se calcula importes? Suponiendo que sea una variable float y no un arreglo.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro int cant;

cant=0;

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,13});printf("¿Cuántas facturas va a ingresar? ");fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&cant); 
 El cant se reemplaza segun las facturas que vaya a ingresar el usuario

Comment: Ahí no se está cargando valores a la variable importes. Lo que tienes que hacer es, ahora suponiendo que es un arreglo, cargar los valores que el usuario da a un arreglo, pero no tiene nada que ver con los decimales, puede ser un arreglo de enteros. Que sea un arreglo no determina el tipo de dato.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro Yo creia que eso era lo q estaba haciendo al poner float importes[cant], segun el numero que ponga el usuario se va a modificar la cantidad de importes.

Answer (score 0):

No, el error no está en el segundo código que pusiste.
Defines un arreglo de float para cargar los importes

> `float importes[cant];`

Pero cuando haces el recorrido no cargas los valores al arreglo, lo cargas a una posición sola.
En la lectura de los datos debes cambiar

```
  scanf("%f",&importes);
```

por

```
  scanf("%f",&importes[x]);
```

De esta forma cargas el los valores de importes al arreglo, y no una posición sola. Recordar que es un arreglo, no una variable, para cargar valores se debe de recorrerlo sin solo guardas la primer posición.
Hay otros errores igual también.

Comment: Ya lo probamos de ambas maneras, pero sigue reconociendo el ultimo nombre que el usuario pone. Es decir, yo ingreso 2 facturas. Al primero Luis, $1500 y al segundo Maria $500. El promedio, el numero de facturas y las facturas mayores a $1000 me lo hace correctamente. Cuando luego decido buscar un nombre según el importe, si yo escribo 1500 no me reconoce a Luis, y si yo escribo 500 me reconoce a María. Ese es nuestro problema, probamos con lo que vos decis pero no nos cambia nada.

Comment: Escribí que hay más errores.

Comment: Estoy investigando

Comment: Nosotros también, espero que podamos llegar a una respuesta !

Comment: A caso el problema reside en que declara `importes` pero no lo define?

Comment: Se define importes si.

Comment: @Mateo osea poner un float y un int? nos da error, se supone q lo estamos definiendo al ponerlo en el float

Comment: Acá no es un problema con el tipo de dato, había unos errores de lectura de datos pero está corregidos.

Comment: No, me refiero a `float importes[] = float[cant];`

Answer (score 0):

Acá tengo otra aproximación, con varios errores corregidos, igualmente presenta errores.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish");
    
    int cant;
    
    cant=0;
    
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,13});printf("¿Cuántas facturas va a ingresar? ");fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&cant);
    
    char nombres[30][cant];
    
    float importes[cant];
    
    int cont1=0;
    int cont2=0;
    int promedio=0;
    char continuar='S';
    
    cont1=cant;
    
    system("cls");
    
    for(int x=0;x<cant;x++)
    {
        while(continuar == 'S' || continuar == 's')
        {
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){10,10+1});printf("Ingrese el nombre del cliente: ");fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s",nombres[cant]);
            
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){10,12+1});printf("Ingrese el importe del cliente: ");fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%f",&importes[cont1]);
            
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,17+1});printf("%s  $  %g", nombres[cont1], importes[cont1]);fflush(stdin);
            
            cont1++;
            
            if(importes[cont1] > 1000)
            {
                cont2++;
            }
            
            promedio += importes[cont1];
            
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),(COORD){37,19});printf("\n\n¿Desea continuar? S para si, N para no\n\n");fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s",&continuar);
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    printf("\nSe cargaron: %d facturas", cont1);
    printf("\nSe cargaron: %d facturas que superan $1000", cont2);
    printf("\nEl promedio de todas las facturas es de: %d",promedio/cont1);
    
    
    float impbusc=0;
    continuar='S';
    
    do
    {
        printf("\n\nIngrese el importe para buscar una factura: ");
        scanf("%f", &impbusc);
        
        for(int x=0;x<cont1;x++)
        {
            if(importes[cont1] == impbusc)
            {
                printf("\nEl importe a buscar es %g y pertenece a %s", impbusc, nombres[cont1]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nEl importe que ingreso no existe!!!\n");
            }
        }
        printf("\n\nDesea continuar? S para si, N para no\n\n");
        scanf("%s",&continuar);
        
    }while(continuar == 's' || continuar == 'S');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probamos este código pero seguimos con el mismo problema, si al primer nombre le damos un importe de 500 y luego lo buscamos segun el importe nos dice que no existe.

Comment: Por qué creaste 2 respuestas? Xd

Comment: porque uno es un error puntua y el otro el programa completo.

Comment: Alejandro! pudimos descubrir el error. Igualamos el cont1==cant y reemplazamos el  importes[x], nombres por nombres [cont1] e importes [cont1] y asi nos mostro ambos resultados :)